# The type of algorithm behind different implementations of the regex.h header on POSIX systems

Tags: c, grep, posix, gnu

I recently read a fantastic article about regular expressions
(see [here](https://swtch.com/%7Ersc/regexp/regexp1.html)) which explained the simplicity
and elegance of the Thompson NFA for matching regular expressions,
as well as the sheer complexity and slowness of other regular
expressions. The diagram given shows Ruby, Python taking
far longer than the Thompson NFA, in fact, the Thompson
NFA had matching times similar to that of notoriously
fast pattern matching UNIX programs, for example, grep and
awk.

My question is, for the <regex.h> header (required
by the POSIX standard) what algorithm does musl, glibc and uclibc use?

I looked at the source for the programs I compared the Thompson NFA
to (GNU/Busybox grep, GNU/Busybox awk) and none of the implementations
used the regex.h header, opting for their own in-house regex matching header.

NOTE: I do NOT mean regular expressions that conform to the POSIX standard - I am speaking specifically about the header supplied by POSIX-compliant (or UNIX-like) systems
called regex.h, which supplies functions and structs used in compiling and matching regular expressions.

Comment: `what algorithm does musl, glibc and uclibc use?` These are open source too. Have you downloaded their sources, and searched for a file like "regex.c" and inspected it's source code? `what algorithm` are there "types of regex algorithms"?

Comment: Your note that "I do NOT mean regular expressions that conform to the POSIX standard - I am speaking specifically about the header supplied by POSIX-compliant (or UNIX-like) systems called regex.h" seems self-contradictory. The `<regex.h>` header is for POSIX-compliant regular expressions, but you say you don't mean POSIX-compliant regular expressions.  Systems such as [PCRE](https://pcre.org) provide their own headers with different names precisely because the interface is not compatible with the interface for `<regex.h>`. I think PCRE provides a `pcre2posix.h` header for the POSIX interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GNU C library implementation – which is what you get when you use `<regex.h>` in Linux (and any other OS when compiling against the GNU C library) – is in [glibc git](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree): [posix/regex.h](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=posix/regex.h;hb=HEAD), [posix/regex.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=posix/regex.c;hb=HEAD), [posix/regex_internal.h](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=posix/regex_internal.h;hb=HEAD), [posix/regex_internal.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=posix/regex_internal.c;hb=HEAD), [posix/regcomp.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=posix/regcomp.c;hb=HEAD), and [posix/regexec.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=posix/regexec.c;hb=HEAD).  The internal files refer to [DFA (deterministic finite automaton)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton), and you can look at the above implementations to see that it indeed implements a DFA.  The git history only reaches back to 2002 or so, but the base implementation is older than that; and I'm too lazy to go read old [glibc-alpha](https://marc.info/?l=glibc-alpha) mailing list archives to uncover the full development history details.  There seem to have been some improvements (when syncing with gnulib regex implementations) in 2018.

Suffice it to say, that for execution, even Thompson NFA is converted to a DFA, and that is what glibc uses to implement <regex.h> functionality.

uClibc's [<regex.h> implementation](https://git.uclibc.org/uClibc/tree/libc/misc/regex) originates from glibc, roughly from the 2002-2006 era, based on the git log (and the copyright assignments in the source files).  So DFA there, too.

[uClibc-ng](https://www.uclibc-ng.org/) is a fork of uClibc (forked around 2014-2015), and has basically the same [<regex.h> implementation](https://cgit.uclibc-ng.org/cgi/cgit/uclibc-ng.git/tree/libc/misc/regex) as uClibc.

[dietlibc](https://www.fefe.de/dietlibc/) uses its own custom (backtracking) implementation, [libregex/rx.c](https://github.com/ensc/dietlibc/blob/master/libregex/rx.c), to provide <regex.h> functionality.

[musl C library](https://musl.libc.org/) has its own [<regex.h> implementation](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/regex) also, based on Ville Laurikari's [TRE](https://github.com/laurikari/tre/) (the approximate regex) library.  I haven't gone through the code to classify it properly, but since its time complexity is linear wrt. the input string (but up to quadratic wrt. the regular expression), I do believe it too is based on finite automata.

The author of Musl has compared various features of different C libraries, including simple regexes, [here](http://www.etalabs.net/compare_libcs.html).  Among other things, it shows that GNU C library implementation has the best runtime for regcomp()+regexec() among the C libraries tested, and all but dietlibc have roughly similar time behaviour.

---

Why, then, would one implement their own regex functionality, and not rely on the one provided by the standard C library?

The reasons I can see are portability to systems where the C library does not have regex functionality (consider e.g. GNU grep, sed, awk on Windows), and to ensure correctness and efficiency of the regex functionality.

Personally, when I write POSIX C code (systems programming – daemons or utilities or libraries for use in Linux or *BSDs), I use `<regex.h>` as provided by the C library.  If I were to write a new grep/sed/awk utility program, I would incorporate the regex library to the sources, so that the utility would be portable across OSes, including those that do not provide `<regex.h>` as part of their C library.  I believe that is the reason you see some dedicated utilities incorporating their own regular expression libraries, too.